# Proof $U\sim V \iff \mu(U \Delta V)=0$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $(X,Y,\mu)$ be a measure space and  $U,V\in Y$. Show that, and define the equivalence relation,

$U\sim V \iff \mu(U \Delta  V)=0$

---

note: the measure is of the symmetric difference.

I know that it is a equivalence relation  if

1. $U\sim U$
2. if $U\sim V$ then $V\sim U$
3. if $U\sim V$ and $V\sim W$ then $U\sim V$

but how do I show the 'iff'-statement whilst defining the equivalence relation?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{1}{U\triangle V}=|\mathbb{1}_U - \mathbb{1}_V|$

Comment: I like to think of it as 'exclusive or': $1_{U\triangle V} = 1_U \oplus 1_V$ :-).

Comment: Show that $U\Delta W\subseteq U\Delta V\cup V\Delta W.$

Comment: Just show the three quoted properties using the given **definition** of $\sim$ where you only use set properties and properties of $\mu$, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation is that the question wants you to assume that you don't know what an equivalence relation formally means.

You are asked to find the meaning of an instance of an of 'equivalence' between measurable sets and prove that it holds iff $\mu(U\Delta V)=0$. Since $U\Delta V = (U/V)\cup (V/U)$, it is a union of disjoint sets, so $\mu(U\Delta V)=\mu(U/V)+\mu(V/U)$. For $\mu(U\Delta V)=0$ to hold, we must have that they are either empty sets or sets of measure zero. This also leads to
$$\mu(U\cup V)=\mu(U\Delta V)+\mu(U\cap V)\implies \mu(U\cup V)=\mu(U\cap V)$$
Therefore, the sets $U$ and $V$ are 'equivalent' under $\mu$, because the sets of the elements on which they differ (i.e. $U/V$ and $V/U$) have measure zero. So

**Definition.** Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $U,V\in \mathscr{A}$. Then if $\mu(U/V)=\mu(V/U)=0$ we say $U \sim V$.

**Lemma.** $U\sim V$ if and only if $\mu(U\Delta V)=0$.

*Proof.* $(\Rightarrow)$. Since $\mu(U\Delta V)=\mu((U/V)\cup(V/U))$, by additivity $\mu(U\Delta V)=\mu(U/V)+\mu(V/U)=0$. $(\Leftarrow)$. Since $\mu(A)\geq 0,\,\forall A \in \mathscr{A}$, we have that $\mu(U/V)+\mu(V/U)=0$ implies that $\mu(U/V)=\mu(V/U)=0$.

Ultimately, you will find that $\mu(U\Delta V)=0$ describes an actual equivalence relation as you defined in the OP (but, for the purpose of the question, you are not supposed to 'know').

Comment: Hey Snoop- Yes the wording makes the intepretation a bit unclear, for me at least. It is show that >>iff statement"", for >>sets in set<<, defines a EQ-relation. I think this is right on the money then.

Comment: @MantlethebantleCS nice, leave an upvote if you like it

Comment: do you think the way it is worded that this is the actual thing that is wanted? That I should not show it defines a equivalence relation? It does really seem so.

Comment: This is what my comment attempts to answer

Comment: @MantlethebantleCS yes it's a wording problem here, and that's an interpretation of what they wanted

Answer (score -1):

The problem is badly worded. If the relation is defined as $$U \sim V \iff \mu(U \Delta V) = 0,$$ there is no point in showing that this equivalence is true as this holds by the very definition. You are probably asked to show that the relation defined above is an equivalence relation (which I assume you know how to do since you did not ask).

Comment: Notice that the OP wants to show that this is an equivalence relation. Though simple to do, it does not hold just by definition.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I notice the opposite: the OP does not ask how to prove that this is an equivalence relation. The only question is about proving the "iff-statement", and while that question does not make sense mathematically, the confusion is justified by the bad problem wording.

Comment: Yes the wording makes the intepretation a bit unclear, for me at least. It is show that >>iff statement"", for >>sets in set<<, defines a EQ-relation.

Comment: It does seem like I have to show that it is a equivalence relation.

Answer (score -1):

1. $U\Delta U = (U\setminus U) \cup (U \setminus U) = \emptyset$. $\mu(U\Delta U) = \mu(\emptyset) = \mu(0)$
2. $U \Delta V = (U \setminus V)\cup (V \setminus U) = (V \setminus U)\cup (U \setminus V) = V \Delta U$. This means that if $U \sim V $ then $\mu(U\Delta V) =0$
   but $\mu(U \Delta V) = \mu(V \Delta U) = 0$ which implies $V \sim U$.
3. If you assume $\mu(U \Delta V) =0$ and $\mu(V \Delta W) =0$ can you prove $\mu(U \Delta W) = 0$ ?

Bonus: notice that this equivalence relationship defines a new measure space $X/\sim$

Comment: I am having trouble with 3.  Does that really hold?